# Is there a way to break down or approximate an $m \times n$ matrix into a product of $m \times k$, $k \times k$ and $k \times n$ matrices?

Tags: matrices, matrix-decomposition, svd

Is there a way to break down or approximate an $m \times n$ matrix into a product of $m \times k$,  $k \times k$ and $k \times n$ matrices, with a certain amount of error? I am not looking for SVD because here, unlike in SVD, $k> m,n$.
Also, m,k,n $\neq 1$. For example, say a $4 \times 3$  matrix into $4\times 8$, $8 \times 8$  and a $8 \times 3$  matrix.
I have been scouring the internet to see if there exists a matrix decomposition of sorts to do this. I would like to know if there is any such in existence.

I am basically trying to solve for X in matrix equation of the format :
$AXB=C$ where X is a diagonal matrix. Matrices $A,B$ and $C$ are known. They can be square or rectangular, complex valued matrices.

Thanks.

Comment: This question is ill posed. 1. If we are free to choose $k$ it is trivial (take $k=n$ and use two identity matrices). 2. If we are not free to chose $k$ and this is, say, $k=1$ it is pretty obvious that such approximations are quite bad in general.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @KurtG. I have edited the question. thanks!

Comment: Still much too vague. Please [edit] the question to give us some idea of what kind of approximation you need, and why. Provide a small example.

Comment: With $k>m,n$, the problem is underdetermined, so you can just do something like the SVD and then pad with zeros as appropriate, or many other possibilities...

Comment: @EthanBolker I've added more details. thanks..

Comment: Any other conditions on the known matrices? Are you sure there is always a solution (I suspect not)? Have you worked out some low dimensional cases by hand?

Comment: Since it is an underdetermined system of equations, I'm thinking there will be infinitely many solutions. But cannot quite figure how to go about it. There are no other constraints on the known matrices.

Comment: It's just a linear system

Answer (score -1):

Consider rank of the matrices on the right - it is not bigger than min of rank of kxk matrix and rank of kxn one. Hence it is not bigger than k. On the left side it can be min of {n,m}.

Answer (score -1):

As various comments said, with $k>m,n$ there are many solutions, including the simple:

$$\begin{bmatrix}a &b & c \\d&e&f\\g&h&i\\j&k&l\end{bmatrix} 
= \begin{bmatrix}a &b & c &0&0&0&0&0\\d&e&f &0&0&0&0&0\\g&h&i &0&0&0&0&0\\j&k&l &0&0&0&0&0\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}1 &0 & 0 &0&0&0&0&0 \\0 &1 &0 & 0 &0&0&0&0\\0 &0 &1 &0 & 0 &0&0&0\\0&0 &0 &1 &0 & 0 &0&0\\0&0&0 &0 &1 &0 & 0 &0\\0&0&0&0 &0 &1 & 0 &0\\0&0&0&0&0 &0 &1 &0 \\ 0 &0&0&0&0&0 &0 &1\end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix}1 &0 & 0 \\ 0 &1 &0  \\0 &0 &1  \\0&0 &0 \\0&0 &0 \\0&0 &0 \\0&0 &0  \\ 0&0 &0 \end{bmatrix}$$